# How to I add numbers to the top of my tic tac toe program?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, tic-tac-toe

I wrote a tic-tac-toe program. The board I made looks like this:

```
1  __|__|__
2  __|__|__
3    |  |
```

The way I have set up the coordinates is that the first box is (1,1), the second (1,2), the third (1,3), the forth (2,1) etc. I wrote the 1, 2, and 3 on the side to make that clear to the user. I would also like to add the 1, 2, 3 to the top of the board. I need some help on how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
class Game

        def initialize
                @board=Array.new
                @board[1]="1  __|"
                @board[2]="__"
                @board[3]="|__"
                @board[4]="\n2  __|"
                @board[5]="__"
                @board[6]="|__"
                @board[7]="\n3    |"
                @board[8]="  "
                @board[9]="|  "
                @turn="x"
                @win_status = false
        end

        def turn
                @turn
        end

        def show_board
                @board.each do |i|
                        print i
                end
                puts ""
        end

        def set_turn #switches turns
        if @turn == "x"
                @turn = "o"
        else @turn == "o"
                @turn = "x"
        end
        end

        def make_move
                puts "Enter x coordinate"
                x=gets.to_i
                puts "Enter y coordinate"
                y=gets.to_i
@board[1]="1  _"+@turn+"|"   if y==1 && x==1
@board[2]="_"+@turn    if y==2 && x==1
@board[3]="|_"+@turn   if y==3 && x==1
@board[4]="\n_"+@turn+"|" if y==1 && x==2
@board[5]="_"+@turn    if y==2 && x==2
@board[6]="|_"+@turn   if y==3 && x==2
@board[7]="\n "+@turn+"|" if y==1 && x==3
@board[8]=" "+@turn    if y==2 && x==3
@board[9]="|"+@turn+" \n"    if y==3 && x==3
        end
def win_combo
                return [[@board[1][1] + @board[2][1] + @board[3][2]], [@board[4][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[6][2]], [@board[7][1] + @board[8][1] + @board[9][1]],[@board[1][1] + @board[4][2] + @board[7][1]], [@board[2][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[8][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[6][2] + @board[9][1]], [@board[1][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[9][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[7][1]]]
        end

        def check_win
                #if some row or column or diagonal is "xxx" or "ooo" then set @win_status = true
                self.win_combo.each do |arr|
                        str = arr.join
                        if str == "xxx" or str == "ooo"
                                return true
                        end
                end
                return false
        end
end


g = Game.new
while g.check_win != true
        g.show_board
        g.set_turn
        g.make_move
end
puts "won"
```

Comment: It would be better to separate the way you're storing the data from the way you're presenting it. Notice that every time you want to deal with that data, you have to go pull it out of the strings, and how the presentation details have found their way into every method, so you can't change them without having to change everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either within your `show_board` function, you can print `1 2 3` there

```
def show_board
    puts "   1 2 3"
    @board.each do |i|
        print i
    end
    puts ""
```

or you can have it as part of the `initialize` and `make_move` blocks as

```
@board[1]="   1 2 3\n" + "1  __|"
```

---

Side note: within `show_board` function, instead of `@board.each .. end` block, you can use

```
@board.each {|i| print i}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are making suggestions why not change the make move method as well to something like this

```
 def make_move(*coords)
       case coords
         when [1,1]    
           @board[1]="1  _"+@turn+"|"
         when [2,1]
           @board[2]="_"+@turn
         when [3,1]
           @board[3]="|_"+@turn
         #...... you get the point 
end
```

Then move the puts to here

```
g = Game.new
while g.check_win != true
    g.show_board
    g.set_turn
    putc "Enter x coordinate: "
    x=gets.to_i
    putc "Enter y coordinate: "
    y=gets.to_i
    g.make_move(y,x)
end
```